# DBA (dBASE) encrypted field called 'XPASSWORD', what is this?

Tags: database, encryption, field, dbase

I'm trying to find the value of a field labeled 'XPASSWORD' in DBF Viewer 2000 ( http://www.dbf2002.com/ ). Does anybody know what encryption technique this field uses? Can anyone help me out?

Thanks for any type of assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What software generated the field? It isn't a standard dbf field type.

Comment: I don't know, I just found these files on my flash drive, and I was wondering if I could find any information about what xpassword was, or how to decrypt it.